# Speed up functions involving (s)apply

Tags: r, performance, apply, sapply

I've profiled my code using the `lineprof` package and identified the bottlenecks to be in the three functions `perm.stat.list`, `G.hat`, and `emp.FDR`. The common theme seems to be the use of `(s)apply`, based on the output of the profiler.

Below is a simplified version of my functions, along with code to generate a reproducible example involving the three functions. I've added comments to better explain what each function is doing and the inputs required.

I'd like to speed up my code considerably because even with `B=10`, the process takes almost half an hour of computation. The input takes a large matrix (`10000 x 10000`), so speed is important. Ideally, I'd like to run `B=5000` permutations, which also increases computation time.

Any tips to improve my code are greatly appreciated.

```
### Functions ###
    perm.stat.list <- function(samp.dat,N1,N2,B){
      perm.list = NULL
      for (b in 1:B){
        #Permute the row "labels", preserving information across columns
        perm.dat.tmp = samp.dat[sample(nrow(samp.dat)),]

        #Compute the permutation-based test statistics
        #Need to save each (1 x M) permutation vector into a list
        perm.list[[b]] = apply(perm.dat.tmp,2,function(y) t.test(y[1:N1],y[(N1+1):(N1+N2)])$statistic)
      }
      return(perm.list)
    }

    G.hat = function(perm.mat,t){
      #Number of permutations
      B = nrow(perm.mat)
      #Compute an empirical distribution along each COLUMN of permutation matrix
      out = apply(perm.mat,2,function(x) sum(x>t,na.rm = TRUE))/B
      return(out)
    }

    emp.FDR <- function(t.vec,mat){
      #For each value in t.vec, apply G.hat function
      out = sapply(t.vec,function(i) sum(G.hat(mat,i),na.rm = TRUE)/max(sum(t.vec > i,na.rm = TRUE),1))
      return(out)
    }
```

.

```
### Generate reproducible example ###

### Global variables ###
#Sample sizes (rows)
N1=3000
N2=7000
#Number of columns
M = 10000
#Number of permutations
B = 10

### Data ###
set.seed(1)
X1 = matrix(rnorm(N1*M),ncol=M)
X2 = matrix(rnorm(N2*M),ncol=M)

### Combine data in one large matrix of size (N1+N2) rows x M columns ###
samp.dat = rbind(X1,X2)

### Compute statistic for each column of samp.dat ###
t.stats = apply(samp.dat,2,
               function(x) t.test(x[1:N1],x[(N1+1):(N1+N2)])$statistic)

### Sort t.stats in decreasing order (not necessarily needed for computation) ###
t.vec = sort(t.stats,decreasing=TRUE)

### Permutation matrix based on the data ###
perm.mat = perm.stat.list(samp.dat=samp.dat,N1=N1,N2=N2,B=B)

eFDR = emp.FDR(t.vec=t.vec,mat=perm.mat)
```

Comment: Did not go through all of it but try `colSums(perm.mat > t, na.rm = TRUE) / B` instead of `apply(perm.mat, 2, function(x) sum(x>t,na.rm = TRUE))/B` in your `G.hat` function.

Comment: Thanks! I think that part definitely improves `G.hat` computation.

Comment: `dim(perm.mat)[1]` is faster than `nrow(perm.mat)` - also for your `G.hat` function.

Comment: Never use sapply non-interactively. Inside a function it should always be vapply.

Comment: You should have a look at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html#t-test

Comment: @F.Privé - I used `t.test` as a stand-in for my actual test statistic function which only calculates the test statistic. I figured `t.test` would be easier to present, as the main issue is with the computing time of the `B` permutations. However, I will try the other suggestions in the link regarding `cmpfun`.

Comment: I was not saying to copy/paste the code there, but rather to use vectorization to apply many tests at once (whatever is the test, if possible) instead of using `apply()`.